# Prove that if $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<1$ then $x_n$ converges to zero.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $x_n$ is a sequence of positive numbers and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}<1$. Prove that $x_n\to 0$.

I have an idea of how to prove this but first I need to know if there is the implicit assumption that the limit exists.

If I can use this assumption then I intend to use the definition of the limit to show that there is a number $r$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}<r<1$. If I can choose epsilon to prove this statement then I will be able to write the proof.

Comment: `if there is the implicit assumption that the limit exists` Since the problem states that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}<1$ then, yes, that's an implicit assumption that the limit does in fact exist.

Comment: OP, could you please clarify what limit you are referring to in the fragment "there is the implicit assumption that the limit exists."?

Answer (score 2):

I think when you say "(...) the limit exists", you mean the limit of $x_n$, right?*

If so, then note that since $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<1$, we have that there exists an $N$ such that if $n>N$, then $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}<1$. Thus, $x_{n+1} <x_n$. It follows that $x_n$ is (eventually) a decreasing sequence, which is bounded below since the $x_n$'s are supposed to be positive. Thus, $x_n$ is indeed convergent.

*I believe this is what you meant because once you know that $\lim x_n=L$ for some $L$, then $\lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac{L}{L}=1$ if $L \neq 0$. Thus, $L$ must be $0$.

Comment: OP's third paragraph suggests my and dxiv's interpretation.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen You have a good point. I had downvoted your answer, but I will retract it. Still, that is a very strange situation, and it is not clear what OP means.

Comment: I agree that perhaps op is doing something strange here. My thoughts were given the notation $r$ suggests a geometric series, they might be going for the stronger claim that $\sum_i x_i$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when they say $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < 1,$ it must mean that the limit exists. Otherwise how could it be less than one?